# Как докопаться до свойства объекта

Tags: php

Есть объект

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#84 (5) { 
    ["name"]=> string(34) "lenovo-laptop-ideapad-z50-back.png" 
    ["tempName"]=> string(44) "E:\serv\OpenServer\userdata\temp\phpD4D6.tmp"
    ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" 
    ["size"]=> int(51033) 
    ["error"]=> int(0) }
}
```

Мне надо докопаться до `name`.

Comment: я так понимаю это вывод `dd()`? тогда можно попробовать `$yourArray[0]->name` . Вместо `yourArray` подставить оригинальное название

Comment: @totorro а в чем суть я пробовал так 
$arr=$yourArray[0]
$array=$arr->name
var_dump($array) 
выдавал null

Comment: а что выдает `dd($yourArray[0])` ?

Comment: @totorro  у меня получилось как вы писали но вот я хочу понять в чем разница оформляйте ответ подтвержу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы получить доступ к свойству объекта в массиве объектов нужно:

1.получаем доступ к объекту использовав его индекс в масиве

2.получаем доступ к свойству обекта использовав оператор `->`

```
$yourArray[0]->name
```